# Mongoose + MongoDB: select:false with select("+attribute.subattribute") Not working

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a Mongoose schema for my user defined as follows

```
var schema   = new mongoose.Schema({
firstName: { type: String, required: true },
lastName: { type: String, required: true },
birthDate: { type: Date, required: true },
gender: { type: String, required: true },
roles: { type: Array, required: true },
authentication: {
    email: { type: String, unique: true, required: true },
    password: { type: String, required: true, select: false },
    token: { type: String, unique: true, select: false },
    tokenExpires: { type: Date, select: false }
});
```

As you can see, on the authentication.password, authentication.token, and authentication.tokenExpires I have utilized the 'select:false' option for those fields. This works like a charm and Mongoose does not return any of those fields on a select but still lets me search for objects with those fields.

Here is the problem. When I do need to have access to those fields in my code and I utilize the '.select("+attribute.attribute")' function on a user 'find' operation I cannot get any of those fields back in the returned object.

```
User.findOne({'authentication.token': bearerHeader}, function(err, user) {
        if (err) {
            res.status(httpMessages.genericServerError.code);
            res.json({
                type: false,
                data: httpMessages.genericServerError.message,
                error: '::USIC:01::'
            });
            next(false);
        } else {
            if(user){
                //Add user to the request for use down the line
                req.currentUser = user;

                //Audit user access
                audit.auditUser(user._id, user.fullName, req.connection.remoteAddress, req.url, req.method);

                next();
            }else{
                req.currentUser = null;
                next();
            }
        }
    }).select("+authentication.token");
```

Here is what I get back demonstrating that the '.select("+attribute")' function is not working on sub-attributes of a document's primary attributes.

```
{ _id: 54b0b297b3ab5dfb724ad727, firstName: 'name', lastName: 'name', birthDate: Fri Jan 01 2500 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (MST), gender: 'm', authentication: { email: 'test@test.com' }
```

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Your `.select()` is in the wrong place. Chaining is: `User.findOne({}).select("+authentication.token").exec(function(err,docs) {});` or `User.findOne({},"+authentication.token",function(err,docs) { })`